# Slow ethernet cable connection - due to slow "Link partner advertised link modes"?

Tags: ethernet

I am using Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS on a new laptop. My ethernet connection seems to be capped at 100MB/s which I would like to change to 1000MB/s. I have tried to use ethernet to do so. This is the stats output of ethtools before I do anything:

```
Settings for eno1:
    Supported ports: [ TP MII ]
    Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                            1000baseT/Full 
    Supported pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
    Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
    Supported FEC modes: Not reported
    Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                            1000baseT/Full 
    Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
    Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
    Advertised FEC modes: Not reported
    Link partner advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                                         100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
    Link partner advertised pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
    Link partner advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
    Link partner advertised FEC modes: Not reported
    Speed: 100Mb/s
    Duplex: Full
    Port: Twisted Pair
    PHYAD: 0
    Transceiver: internal
    Auto-negotiation: on
    MDI-X: Unknown
    Supports Wake-on: pumbg
    Wake-on: d
    Link detected: yes
```

I have tried to set the speed to 1000 with the following command, however,  I immediately lose the connection and the output changes to unknown:

```
user:~$ sudo ethtool -s eno1 speed 1000 duplex full
user:~$ sudo ethtool eno1
Settings for eno1:
    Supported ports: [ TP MII ]
    Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                            1000baseT/Full 
    Supported pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
    Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
    Supported FEC modes: Not reported
    Advertised link modes:  1000baseT/Full 
    Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
    Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
    Advertised FEC modes: Not reported
    Speed: Unknown!
    Duplex: Unknown! (255)
    Port: Twisted Pair
    PHYAD: 0
    Transceiver: internal
    Auto-negotiation: on
    MDI-X: Unknown
    Supports Wake-on: pumbg
    Wake-on: d
    Link detected: no
```

I'm assuming that this is due to the "Link partner advertised link modes" not including 1000baseT/Full before setting the speed to 1000. However, my internet provider swears that it's not their router. In my old flat with my old computer, the ethernet cable was easily able to handle 1000MBit/s.

Anyone any ideas what could be going wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output of `ethtool` clearly shows that the device on the other end of the Ethernet cable plugged into your `eno1`port only supports 100 MBit/s as maximum speed. To resolve this:

- Check where that cable is plugged in.
- If it is a switch, replace it by a Gigabit capable model.
- If it is your Internet provider's router, talk to your provider again, quoting your `ethtool` result.